# HTML document was not declared

Tags: php, html, firefox

This is about retriving the data in form of CSV from Mysql Table : -

Code , I tried :-

```
<?php
// mysql database connection details
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "hello";
    $dbname = "mysql2csv";

// open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or     die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

// fetch mysql table rows
    $sql = "select * from tbl_books";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " .     mysqli_error($connection));

    $fp = fopen('books.csv', 'w');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

    fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
```

?>

Errors Obtained...

04:12:27.093 The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.1 mysql2csv.php.

your help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those lines to your html header

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

**Edit:**
If you are using PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I just wanted to run the php script on the server and i don't have HTML header

Comment: Do you want to run this on terminal/ command line interface ?

Comment: I run this on localhost mysql database , during run time showing the above problem

Comment: I mean do you run this script via browser ? or with command line interface ?

Comment: You can add this header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');